# Задача с CodeWars: Простой интерпретатор ассемблера

Tags: python, алгоритм, ассемблер, интерпретатор

Не понимаю где я допустил ошибку. Вот условие [задачи](https://www.codewars.com/kata/58e24788e24ddee28e000053) (через переводчик все прогнал, поэтому могут быть некоторые несущественные неточности):

```
Мы хотим создать простой интерпретатор ассемблера, который будет поддерживать следующие инструкции:

 - mov x y - копирует y(либо постоянное значение, либо содержимое регистра) в регистр x
 - inc x - увеличивает содержимое реестра x на единицу
 - dec x - уменьшает содержимое регистра x на единицу
 - jnz x y - переходит к инструкции y на шаг вперед (положительное значение означает вперед, отрицательное означает назад, y может быть регистром или константой), но только если x(константа или регистр) не равна нулю

Имена регистров указываются в алфавитном порядке (только буквы). Константы всегда являются
целыми числами (положительными или отрицательными).

Примечание: jnz инструкция перемещается относительно самой себя. Например, смещение -1 будет
продолжаться с предыдущей инструкции, а смещение 2 будет пропускать следующую инструкцию.

Функция примет входной список с последовательностью инструкций программы и выполнит их.
Программа завершается, когда больше нет инструкций для выполнения, и возвращает словарь
(таблицу в COBOL) с содержимым регистров.

Кроме того, каждому inc// в регистре всегда будет предшествовать a в регистре, поэтому вам
не нужно беспокоиться о неинициализированных регистрах dec jnz mov.
```

Пример:

```
["mov a 5"; "inc a"; "dec a"; "dec a"; "jnz a -1"; "inc a"]

visualized:

mov a 5
inc a
dec a
dec a
jnz a -1
inc a
```

Приведенный выше код в словах:

```
установите a для регистрации значение 5,
увеличить его стоимость на 1,
уменьшить его значение на 2,
затем уменьшайте его значение, пока оно не станет равным нулю ( jnz a -1 переход к предыдущей инструкции, если a оно не равно нулю)
а затем увеличить его значение на 1, оставив регистр a равным 1
```

функция должна вернуть:

```
{'a': 1}
```

мое решение:

```py
class Interpreter:
    counter = 0
    program = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.regs = {}

    def mov(self, val_1: str, val_2: str):
        if val_2.isalpha():
            val_2 = self.regs[val_2]
        self.regs[val_1] = int(val_2)

    def inc(self, reg: str):
        self.regs[reg] += 1

    def dec(self, reg: str):
        self.regs[reg] -= 1


def simple_assembler(program):
    len_ = len(program)
    ex = Interpreter()
    Interpreter.program = program
    while Interpreter.counter < len_:
        spl = Interpreter.program[Interpreter.counter].split()
        try:
            controller(spl[0], spl[1], spl[2], ex=ex)
        except IndexError:
            controller(spl[0], spl[1], ex=ex)
    Interpreter.counter = 0
    Interpreter.program = None
    return ex.regs


def controller(instruction, val_1, val_2=None, ex=None):
    if not val_2:
        match instruction:
            case 'inc':
                ex.inc(val_1)
            case 'dec':
                ex.dec(val_1)
    else:
        match instruction:
            case 'mov':
                ex.mov(val_1, val_2)
            case 'jnz':
                if val_1.isalpha():
                    val = val_1
                    if ex.regs[val] <= 0:
                        Interpreter.counter += 1
                        return
                else:
                    val = int(val_1)
                    if val <= 0:
                        Interpreter.counter += 1
                        return

                if val_2.isalpha():
                    step = ex.regs[val_2]
                else:
                    step = int(val_2)

                next_instruction = Interpreter.program[Interpreter.counter + step].split()[0]
                controller(instruction=next_instruction, val_1=val, ex=ex)
                Interpreter.counter = Interpreter.counter + step
                return
    Interpreter.counter += 1


# первая тестовая строка, тут все ок, при ее передаче в simple_assembler() ответ должен быть: {'a': 1}
s1 = '''\
mov a 5
inc a
dec a
dec a
jnz a -1
inc a'''

# вторая и последняя тестовая строка из базовых тестов, у меня получается ответ: 
# {'c': 12863, 'b': 12863, 'a': 12863}, а правильный: {'a': 409600, 'c': 409600, 'b': 409600}
s2 = '''\
mov c 12
mov b 0
mov a 200
dec a
inc b
jnz a -2
dec c
mov a b
jnz c -5
jnz 0 1
mov c a'''
# print(simple_assembler(s1.splitlines()))
print(simple_assembler(s2.splitlines()))
```

Мне бы понять, что я  делаю не так: неправильно понимаю логику работы некоторых инструкций? Например, `jnz x y`, как я понимаю, должен перебрасывать "указатель" выполнения на `y` шагов в зависимости от знака, и выбирать инструкцию, которая располагается на получившийся позиции с регистром `x`, если конечно число `x != 0` или его содержимое, если `x` - это регистр. А после этого инструкции идут также по порядку или управление возвращается сразу к `jnz`?

Comment: Разумеется, дальше инструкции идут по порядку.

Comment: Вообще плохая идея делать интерпретаторы с помощью класса. Именно поэтому так сложно искать ошибки. Сделали бы классический главный цикл, подпрограммы для каждой команды и сразу бы все встало на место.

Comment: @Глеб, да, конечно, добавил ссылку в вопрос

Comment: @Глеб, вероятно, вы правы. Просто я уже делал подобные задачи, и в некоторых авторы изначально подразумевали, что интерпретатор будет реализован в виде класса

Comment: Ясно. Еще, кстати, валидацию простых языков ассемблера лучше делать не с помощью сложных обработчиков, а регуляркой. Гарантирую — код сократится на половину.

Comment: @Глеб, понял, учту ваш совет, спасибо

Comment: Не нужны здесь регулярки. Четыре команды с определённым количеством аргументов - match/case достаточно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `jnz` ошибка. Все проверки должны быть на (не)равенство нулю (Jump if Not Zero). После `jnz` инструкции идут по порядку с нового места.

Проверка `if not val_2:` сработает для нуля. Надо писать `if val_2 is not None:`.

`match` умеет различать списки разных длин.

```
def simple_assembler(program):
    regs = {}
    ip = 0
    
    def get_value(x):
        return regs[x] if x.isalpha() else int(x) 

    while 0 <= ip < len(program):
        match program[ip].split():
            case ['mov', x, y]:
                regs[x] = get_value(y)
                ip += 1
            case ['inc', x]:
                regs[x] += 1
                ip += 1
            case ['dec', x]:
                regs[x] -= 1
                ip += 1
            case ['jnz', x, y]:
                ip += get_value(y) if get_value(x) != 0 else 1

    return regs
```

**P.S.** Вместо интерпретатора можно написать оптимизирующий компилятор. Но он будет раза в три больше.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Команду условного перехода вы совсем не так поняли. Правильно:

jnz x y - Jump `y` instructions if `x` is Not Zero

Методы simple_assembler и controller нужно включить в класс Interpreter. simple_assembler я бы переименовал в Execute, а controller - в Cpu. Методы mov, inc и dec лишние, всё это делается внутри Cpu.

То, что вы назвали counter, называется IP - instruction pointer. Вам не придётся передавать его в Cpu, так как всё это будет внутри класса. В Cpu передавайте список, а не элементы по отдельности.

В цикле интерпретатора я бы сделал анализ аргуметов - число или регистр. Если аргумент регистр, то вместо него сразу бы передавал в Cpu значение. Как правило, в таких задачах подразумевается, что входные данные без ошибок, поэтому можно смело вместо регистра передавать значение. Значение будет вторым аргументом в mov, и может быть и первым, и вторым аргументом в jnz.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию!

Comment: По поводу simple_asembler и controller - я бы изначально с удовольствием их сделал частью класса, чтобы не делать эти странные передачи экземпляра между функциями, но там в задаче изначально simple_assembler был в виде функции, и я уже от этого плясал, думая, что возникнут проблемы с тестами